# NSUserdefaults global defaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am making an application in which i have added the settings(nsuserdefaults)

The problem is in my mainviewcontroller i declare user defaults and get its values.
However since viewdidload is not called after user goes to settings and comes back to the app.
My settings does not update.

I tried declaring user defaults in app delegate applicationwillenterforeground 
but how will i pass the message to mainviewcontroller.

variables defined in app delegate are not recognised in mainviewcontroller.

Update : I have declared

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults];
}
```

i have toggle switch in settings which has identifier enabled_preference so i wrote

```
   else
{
    [PlaySound prepareToPlay];      
    [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"enabled_preference"];
    BOOL loop = [prefs boolForKey:@"enabled_preference"];
    NSLog(@" %d",loop);
    do {
          [PlaySound play];
    } while (loop ==YES);
```

it is logging 0 in console however i have set default to yes in plist

Answer (score 2):

you can use any where in app if you set object to NSUserDefaults.. no need to create object in appDelagate...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Ramu" forKey:@"iCustomerId"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

you can get that value in entire app using below line

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"iCustomerId"]
```

Comment: thanks for reply . 2 questions now.  i have declared user defaults in view did load. will i be able to access it it flipsideviewcontroller.?              Second i have toggle switch in settings which has identifier enabled_preference so i wrote BOOL loop = [prefs boolForKey:@"enabled_preference"];
        NSLog(@" %d",loop);     it is logging 0 in console however i have set default to yes in plist

Comment: i didn't get your point...as i said no need declare any object in viewdidload or viewwillappear just use two options..1.setbool forkey and 2.boolForkey

Comment: if i didn't put   NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults]; in viewdidload and outside it .. it is saying initializer element not compile time constant.  and my real question is boolforkey is returning 0 while it is 1 by default

Comment: By default it will return NO means 0 if set YES Then then it will return 1(YES)

Comment: i know it will return1 for yes.. but that is the problem . in my settings root.plist i have set default to yes. but its is still returning 0 for it.???

Answer (score 1):

When you pop back your ViewDidLoad wont be called.
You need to write that code in

ViewWillAppear

and that is called every time you to that view controller.

Comment: thanks for reply . 2 questions now.  i have declared user defaults in view did load. will i be able to access it it flipsideviewcontroller.?              Second i have toggle switch in settings which has identifier enabled_preference so i wrote BOOL loop = [prefs boolForKey:@"enabled_preference"];
        NSLog(@" %d",loop);     it is logging 0 in console however i have set default to yes in plist

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is not a good fit. There are many cases where it will not be called when you need it to, and other cases where it will be called more often than you want for this case.

Comment: Yes that would be called,you can even use notifications as Abhi has said.All depends upon you how would you like to access and use..

Comment: @Abhi Beckert, you may be right,but without registering to any notification this could be done and all depends upon the way as he wants to use....Notification has its own place where as ViewWillAppear has its own place.....

Answer (score 1):

Any object can register itself for the application did become active notification. Just do that in your MainViewController:

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; // your app may crash randomly if you don't do this

  [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  // check user defaults for changes
}

@end
```

Depending on how your app is structured this particular `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method may or may not be called the first time your app is launched, you'll have to check, but it will always be called after that.

Comment: thanks for reply . 2 questions now.  i have declared user defaults in view did load. will i be able to access it it flipsideviewcontroller.?              Second i have toggle switch in settings which has identifier enabled_preference so i wrote BOOL loop = [prefs boolForKey:@"enabled_preference"];
        NSLog(@" %d",loop);     it is logging 0 in console however i have set default to yes in plist